# Subversion create user and provide access rules to repositories

Tags: svn

How to create a new subversion user from ubuntu server and provide access rules to all the repositories present in the server

--
Thanks

Comment: It depends how you are accessing the SVN repository http/svn/?

Comment: Please read [Chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.html) and [Chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) of the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) -- you have _so many choices ahead of you, no answer could provide enough to help you_.

Comment: @ Khmarbaise - am accessing it via svn command

Comment: svn can be accessed via *http or svn of file* protocol with svn commands in **any** case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to /etc/subversion

## cd /etc/subversion

## htpasswd -m passwd testing(username)

move the record of  "testing" username in passwd file to /home/svn/gsui/conf/passwd
/home/svn/gsui is my svn server's root directory.

and save the "passwd"  file. And new user is created.